# How to add a simple design in classic editor plugin creating post page through another Wp plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to add simple html form **without breaking the extisiting design or license of Classic Editor plugin which is GPLv2**

I added simple code in `classic-edior.php` file (I'm not sure If it's the best way but I'm making a wp-plugin that must this simple form comes in Classic Edior creating post page so I can't use adding short code maybe?.

```
function myfunction()
{
    // after this next, plain HTML
?>
    <!-- HTML !-->

    <!-- HTML !-->

    <div style="      ">

        <button class="button-2" role="button" style=" display: flex; margin-left:25%;  justify-content: center; ">Button</button>

        <form action="/action_page.php" style="   margin: auto; width: 50%;border: 3px solid black; padding: 10px;">
            <label for="fname">Action:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=" "><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>


    <!-- more HTML code here -->
    <?php   // back to PHP
    // .. some more PHP stuff
    return;
}
myfunction();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the code between the ending question mark

For e.g.

```
function myfunction()
{
// PASTE THE HTML CODE HERE
}
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).